# Time picker in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am building an application using PyQt5 where it requires date picker and time picker.
for date picker I have used QCalendarWidget whereas I'm not able to find anything for time picker.
if there is something for time picker also please let me know how to use it as I want to have a popup where I can select time in hours and minutes.

Comment: Do you need to use a `QTimeEdit`? The documentation pretty much tells how to use it.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "time picker", as there are lots of different ways to do so: besides [QTimeEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeedit.html) (which is a sort of spin box that allows to *type* time and eventually use arrows to change the value), there are other ways to do so, including "clock-alike" widgets. Note that Qt doesn't provide any of that, so you have to implement it on your own, possibly by creating a custom QWidget subclass.

Comment: I want something like clock-widget which can be used in popup and user can pick hours and minute from it.

Comment: I will use QTimeEdit as a last resort

Comment: @SadiqueKhan Then, as said, it can only be done with a custom subclass: either you find one done by somebody else, or you do it.

Comment: Thanks.  I came here with the same question.  Thanks to @musicmante we have an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Qt provides that widget.
Create widget and connect it with event. In example I added label to display current value from input.

```py
datetime = QDateTimeEdit(self)
label = QLabel("Current date & time: ", self)
datetime.dateTimeChanged.connect(lambda: dt_method())

def dt_method():
    value = datetime.dateTime()
    label.setText("Current date & time: " + str(value))
```

The result will be displayed in following format:

> PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime( ***year***, ***month***, ***day***,
> ***hour***, ***minutes***)

Comment: I want only hour and minute just like in calendarwidget which can be shown in popup  and user can select time